# Cutting triangles from quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

I have a job installing a mirror and I have no idea how to cut the mirror in the shape needed.

I currently have 2 pieces of glass that are 54 in by 130 in. I am hoping I only need the 2 pieces to complete the job
The shape would be a quadrilateral with uneven heights, but if making the heights even makes it easier that is fine.
The person would like 12 pieces of glass to complete the shape. (attached are diagrams)

simple (same height quadrilateral) [image]

the real wall
[image]

Any direction I can get help in understanding how to get the measurements for the cutting is greatly appreciated!

PS. sorry for the completely bad diagrams (in case it was not clear they are not to scale)

Comment: Are the points where the blue lines touch the sides of the quadrilateral midpoints? If not, how are the blue lines defined?

Comment: yeah sorry forgot to explain that the blue lines are at the midpoints of the respective side.

Comment: Why the lengths of the sides of the perfect rectangle ar different? (92 1/8 and 91 7/8)

Comment: @mrprottolo It is not a rectangle.

Comment: Place the two $50\times 130$ glasses together horizontally, align their common side/bottom with the middle lines/bottom of the wall.move shape $2$ on top of shape $11$ and rotate around $45^\circ$. move shape $4$ on top of shape $10$ and do the same thing,  There are enough room on the top of the glasses to hold the rotated shapes.